# Set left and right border-like on highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way I could set a gridline on start point and end point of x-axis or somehow a **left-and-right border** on the highcharts without displaying the entire gridline.
For further understanding, please refer to the attached image[image]

For reference see: http://jsfiddle.net/f0j6tjxy/

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
      inverted: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      reversed: false,
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.value + 'km';
        }
      },
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature'
      },
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.value + '°';
        }
      },
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Temperature',
      data: [
        [0, 15],
        [10, -50],
        [20, -56.5],
        [30, -46.5],
        [40, -22.1],
        [50, -2.5],
        [60, -27.7],
        [70, -55.7],
        [80, -76.5]
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: can use render to get result http://jsfiddle.net/u47ogme8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the minorTicks to achieve this. In the following way:

```
xAxis: {
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  minorTicks: true,
  minorGridLineWidth:1,
  minorTickInterval: 80,
  ...
}
```

If you have a dynamic min/max, it is possible to set this dynamically, e.g. in the load event.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/f0j6tjxy/3/

---

**Edit:**

For dynamic min/max you could include this:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      minValue = this.xAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMin;
      maxValue = this.xAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMax;
      gridlineDistance = maxValue - minValue;
      this.update({
        xAxis: {
          minorGridLineWidth: 1,
          minorTicks: true,
          minorTickInterval: gridlineDistance,
        }
      }, true)
    }
  }
},
```

As long as there is a `majorTick` at the start and the end of the chart, this will assign the `minorTick`s to draw a grid there.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/f0j6tjxy/12/

However, for **live-updated** data, it is harder. One way to do it would be to add `plotLines` at the ends like this:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      // set up the updating of the chart each second
      var series = this.series[0];
      var xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
      setInterval(function() {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        xAxis.update({
          plotLines: [{
            value: x - 60000,
            color: '#f2f2f2',
            width: 1
          }, {
            value: x,
            color: '#f2f2f2',
            width: 1
          }]
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
},
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/1L9aak94/29/

This is hardcorded to 60k milliseconds, but that could easily be made dynamic by using the `getExtremes()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. May I know how will I use this in a dynamic random data like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/1L9aak94/

Comment: @gio_gio Updated answer to include dynamic and live dynamic solutions.